# Make Find function for Notepad with TextBox in C#

Tags: c#

I am making a copy of a Windows Notepad and I'm stuck at "FIND" function. Honestly I have no clue how to make it. I've been searching for a while and everyone suggests RichTextBox because it has implemented find function but the point is i need to make it using textbox.

So I've made new form, connected it with main form. I made class which looks like:

```
public bool FindAndSelect(string TextToFind, bool MatchCase, bool UpDown)
{
}
```

But I don't know what to write in it to work. I've made find button in find form with function

```
if (((fNotepad)this.Owner).FindAndSelect(this.textBoxFind.Text, this.rbUpDown.Checked, this.cbMatchCase.Checked) == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cant find selected text");
}
else this.Close();
```

And I know what I have to do but I don't know to code it .. any help would be appreciated! ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) to find the position of the match within the text box.  This will let you use the [TextBox.SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `SelectionLength` to set the selection.

```
public bool FindAndSelect(string TextToFind, bool MatchCase)
{
     var mode = MatchCase ? StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

     int position = textBox.Text.IndexOf(TextToFind, mode);

     if (position == -1)
         return false;

     textBox.SelectionStart = position;
     textBox.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length;
     return true;
}
```

Note the above doesn't handle "up/down" - to do that, you'd need to compare against the current `SelectionStart` position, and see if there's a match after that.  There is an overload of [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to specify a starting point, which would make that easier to handle.

Comment: thanks. and where do i run this method? in my find form or in my main form? im confused

Comment: yeah i get that , but then when i'm in the Find_form of my program i need to call that method on button press and i call it with function:

((Notepad_form)this.Owner).FindAndSelect() ... but compiler doesnt want to execute that line ... i've made Find_Form.Owner = this; in my main class so i dont get why i cant see the method

Answer (score 0):

To start, try something like this, in the btnFind_Click event:

```
private btnFind_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CountStringOccurrences(txtNotePad.Text, txtToFind.Text) > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found 1 or multiple matches");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Didn't found match...");
    }
}

//CountStringOccurrences, takes full text + string to match with
//Returns the amount of matches found in full text
public static int CountStringOccurrences(string text, string pattern)
{
    // Loop through all instances of the string 'text'.
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
    {
        i += pattern.Length;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string[] a = new string[100];`
        string word = tb.Text;

        WinFormsApp2.Form1 fi = new WinFormsApp2.Form1();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (word == fi.find[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("FOUNDED");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please explain, how your code solves the problem in the question. Also, edit your answer to fix your code block (I would do it, but the edit queue is full).